# Can we use 2 different passport local strategies in one application? If so, then how?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

So, I've been developing this application, that has say **2 different levels of authentication**.

And by that I mean that in the first level, the authentication that takes place, is for a group account, i.e. a group of individuals, who have access to a single group account, into which they can log in after giving their credentials (I want to specify that the group credentials are basically a group username and password).

In the second level, each of these members can now log into their individual profiles by giving a six digit pass-code and access their individual profiles.

So I implemented the first part successfully, using passportjs.  But now I am confused as to how I can authenticate individual profiles using passportjs. I tried building a simple authentication system that simply compares the hashed pass-code for authentication. But the problem is that it is too basic and I'm unable to authenticate the requests like in passport.

**So is there any way I can use multiple passport local strategies somehow?**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by passing an additional parameter to `passport.use`

Like so:

```
  passport.use('level1', new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
    // Authentication stuff
  }));

  passport.use('level2', new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
    // Other authentication stuff
  }));
```

Then when you want to use either, you can call `passport.authenticate('level1')` or `passport.authenticate('level2')` depending on which one you need